# league of legends item that increase damage when critical hit

Tags: league-of-legends

I know only Infinity Edge can increase the damage. 
Any other items to increase more?
I want to maximize the damage of Miss Fortune.

Comment: The currently favored build for MF is not based on crit chance at all. You should be building Lethality - Youmuu's, Duskblade, Edge of Night are core items for her. Black Cleaver is also really good with her ult.

Comment: Why lethality is best for MF instead of critical damage? I mean her Q is a painful hit and I focus to maximum that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Her Q does a lot of physical damage, and though it can crit, it only does so consistently if your crit chance is high enough. That means your Q damage isn't going to be very high until late game. If you build Lethality, your Q will do a lot more damage early game. And in the current meta, early game is king.

Answer (score 3):

As of patch 8.11 the only item that increases **Critical Damage** is the *Stormrazor*, that *guarantees a critical strike for 160% damage (+1% per 1.5% critical strike chance, max 200%)*. This means that this guaranteed Critical Strike will only do as much damage as a regular critical shot.

With that said, patch 8.11 changed how *Infinity Edge* works, and instead of increasing critical damage it now grants a passive that converts *15% of critical strike damage to true damage*.

Therefore, as of this patch there are no longer items that increase *Critical Damage*.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one item that will increase the damage done by a critical hit. That's **Infinity Edge**. As said above.

But, that doesn't mean you can provide MF with more damage. Even though Lethality MF is better you can still get alot of fun with Critical MF. My recommendation is if you're building Critical, buy: **Statikk Shiv** and **Rapid Firecannon**

Good luck on trying it out!